# Reading all data of SAPUI5 common table

Tags: sapui5

Is there anyway to read all rows of a SAPUI5 commons table because of oTable.getRows();
returns only the first 10 visible rows but i need all.
I know i can get the table model with the data but there is at the moment the input data not saved because no two way bindet Model
So how can I reciev reading all rows of a common table in UI5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why not use two-way binding instead? ;-)

Also, if you have a table which is bound to an ODataModel, and you need to make (multiple) changes to the data before submitting it back, it's best to use a JSONModel for these changes -- so you have the added benefit the user can revert back to the original state if the he needs to 'reset' changed values. Then add the changed objects to the payload when submitting your ODataModel

Comment: yeah you're right but my model wan't work like my second question is showing, but i think i could have answered this by myself because i tryed many diffrent things to get all data readed that there is no possible way too read all data at the moment.

Comment: I would advise to get the model working, because using the table's `getRows` is asking for trouble -- what happens when sorting, grouping, filtering, let alone you need to retrieve data yourself from the rows/columns instead of having a handy Javascript array of objects ;-)

Comment: To add to that: if you have one-way binding on your table, it doesn't really make sense to retrieve all rows of the table. The user can never change values in the table that are not visible, so you don't need to retrieve these values from the table to update them e.g. in the model.

Comment: that the point where the problems started we need user input so we changed some into Textfields and made them editable and we needed the data with one way binding not possible only with reading the table or changing the model but model still makes problems.